# Como iterar sobre las columnas de un dataframe agrupado

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Hola tengo un dataframe(sin la columna ColumnaCreada) eso es lo que pretendo conseguir:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"id":("a","a","a","b","b","b"),
                   "Factor": (True,False, False, True,False, False),
                   "MarcaTemp": (1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  "ColunaCreada":(2,2,2,5,5,5)}
                  )
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es agrupar por id, y después hallar el valor minimo en marca de tiempo donde el Factor cambie de T a F y usar ese valor en todas las columnas de ese id dentro de la columna que creo para ello llamada ColumnaCreada. He probado esto, pero no consigo que ponga el valor bien ya que pone el ultimo valor a todos, es como que no itera bien sobre el sub grupo.

Esto es lo que probe:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('id'):
    print(name)
    #Para el id en el que estoy en esa fase de la iteraccion busco que factor
    #sea True y después de esos selecciono el valor mínimo que sera el valor
    #que busco asignar.
    x = df.loc[(df['id'] == name) & (df.Factor== False)]
    time = x["MarcaTemp"].min()
    #Despues simplemente voy igualando en los campos para asignarlo a cada 
    #fila que le corresponda ese valor.
    df["ColumnaCreada"] = time
```

Entonces no se si debo hacer otra iteraccion para cada fila dentro del id especifico que estoy, y en caso de ser así como se haría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo siguiente parece que funcione bien:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                   "Factor": (True, False, False, True, False, False),
                   "MarcaTemp": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)}
                  )
df["ColumnaCreada"] = 0
for name, group in df[df["Factor"] == False].groupby("id"):
    tiempo = group["MarcaTemp"].min()
    df.loc[df["id"] == name, "ColumnaCreada"] = tiempo
print(df)
```

Resultado:

```
  id  Factor  MarcaTemp  ColumnaCreada
0  a    True          1              2
1  a   False          2              2
2  a   False          3              2
3  b    True          4              5
4  b   False          5              5
5  b   False          6              5
```

Comment: Esto es! Muchas gracias! Ya entendí como lo hiciste, haciendo ese loc de nombre y columna!